# concantenate csv files by column and include timestamp from file name

Tags: bash, csv

I have 500 csv files i want to join

I'll explain the csv format first each csv file is named log-yyyy-mm-dd.hh:mm:ss.csv

its structured without column headers

```
eventID,number
```

so for example

```
FLAGS-2,16
DOOR6-234,800
```

i'd like to format this data like this

```
eventID,filename,filename,filename  ---and so on for the 500+ files
```

```
eventID,log-2019-03-10.21:00:01.csv,log-2019-03-15.12:00:01.csv
FLAGS-2,16,54
FLAGS-3,16,9
```

I first looked at doing it with bash and awk but gave in when i found that occasionally if data is not logged in the file. It doesn't store a number for that eventID

when i do  `find . -name '*.csv' | xargs wc -l`

some files have 7803 lines some have 7800 and so on

so in one file i could have the following

```
FLAGS-2,16
FLAGS-3,19
FLAGS-4,02
```

and the next

```
FLAGS-2,16
FLAGS-4,02
```

what would be the next best approach

thanks

Comment: Do you really want to do this in `Bash`? I would recommend scripting language like `Python`

Comment: Joining the files can be done with `join`, but I would advise against it as `join` can only process two files at once. You would have to call `join` 500 times. An `awk` script should do the trick relatively fast.

Comment: the environment is limited, its just a router and the router needs to put the logs together at the end of the week and send the data via smtp. i cant install python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a bash/awk solution, albeit not the most efficient approach.  But it's clear enough to easily understand and maintain.

Basically, it first creates the header line and `joined.csv` file.  Then there's a loop for finding all the unique ids within all your csv files.  Then look for each `key` in each csv file, appending the value to `line`.  And then finally appending each `line` to the resulting `joined.csv` file.

```
#!/bin/bash

header=eventID
for csv_file in $( ls -1 log*csv)
do
    header="$header,$csv_file"
done
echo $header > joined.csv

for key in $( awk -F, '{print $1}' log*csv | sort -u )
do
    line=$key
    for csv_file in $( ls -1 log*csv)
    do
        value=$( grep $key $csv_file | awk -F, '{print $2}' )
        line="$line,$value"
    done
    echo $line >> joined.csv
done
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: wow wasnt expecting the full solution, I had to add a sed in there to handle windows eol but my error in explanation i never imagined the logs would have windows eols on a linux box. but i can see how very inefficient it is surely there is a better way to write out a variable to a specific column like pandas does in python

Comment: is the -1 necessary in the ls? I always thought the when using ls in a script it defaulted to -1 and -1 was just so a user could visually see it. i'm probably wrong but if you dont ask you don't learn :)

Comment: hi, I think you're right about the -1.  I'll be honest, I don't exactly know why.  Maybe ls does work different when in interactive mode, or bash interpreter delimits new lines and tabs?  Probably another question... :)